# Intersection between dictionary and list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a code that receives a response from post requests in format json and there is a list ID (`id_s`).

```
id_descript = []
id_s=[]

for k, d in enumerate(id_descript):
    answer = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(data) , headers=headers)
    response=answer.json()
    print(response)

for i in id_s:
    print(i)
#id_443081
#id_187360
```

I want to process the results and write them down in one list (`result`). An example of how this should be displayed:

Comment: where are the ids from.. there are 2 different ones.. do you want to change the id or is it the orignal from the response?

Comment: You wrote "one list (result)" but then wrote `result = {}`. So which is it? A list or a dict?

Comment: Based on your example you would write `result[response['id']] = response['build']`. But it's not clear from the rest of your question if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I want to get a dictionary

Comment: The value shown in comments following the `print(response)` is not in valid JSON format...so I doubt that is what it is. Also, what's `id_s` (i.e. where are its contents defined)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple key-value assignment is often the best option:

```
id_s = ['id_443081', 'id_187360']

res = {}

for k, d in enumerate(id_descript):
    answer = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(data) , headers=headers)
    response = answer.json()
    res[id_s[k]] = response['build']
```

You can then display the results in any format you require. For example, if you are looking for a list of tuples, use `lst = list(res.items())`.

Comment: answer.json() has an id, but I need to append an id from list id_s, see an example in the description.

Comment: @st_jonni, See update, you can use `id_s[k]` as the key when setting items. That makes the link. Helpfully you are already using `enumerate`.